# How to make three level selection in html by using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

here two level selection are given with select tag , i want to make one more level by adding one more select tag.

if i selected madhya pradesh from first select tag then selected Rewa from second selection tag then option list should come into third selection tag with reference to Rewa such as Rewa appeared with respect to madhya pradesh.

> tahshil[Rewa] =
>   {"Huzur","Hanumana","Teonthar","Mangawan","Jawa","Sirmour",
>   "Mauganj","Naigarhi","Semaria","Gurh","Raipur - Karchuliyan"}

```
        <html>
        <head>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var countries = [ ];
            countries["Madhya Pradesh"] = ["Indore","Jabalpur","Bhopal","Raisen","Rajgarh","Sehore","Vidisha","Morena","Sheopur","Bhind","Ashoknagar","Shivpuri","Rewa"];
            countries["Uttar Pradesh"] = ["Allahabad","Moradabad","Ghaziabad","Azamgarh", "Lucknow","Kanpur Nagar","Jaunpur","Sitapur","Bareilly","Gorakhpur","Agra"];


            function switchCountry(selCountry)
            {
                var citySel = selCountry.form.City;
                for ( var s = citySel.options.length-1; s > 0; --s )  
                {
                    citySel.options[s] = null;
                }

                var chosen = selCountry.options[selCountry.selectedIndex].text;
                var cList = countries[chosen];
                if ( cList != null )
                {
                    for ( var i = 0; i < cList.length; ++i )   
                    {
                        citySel.options[i+1] = new Option(cList[i],cList[i]);
                    }
                }
            }


        </script>

        </head>
        <body>  
        <br>
        <form>
            <center>    

                <h3>Select State of shop : <select name="Country" onchange="switchCountry(this);">
                <option value = "">Choose state</option>


                <option value="mdp">Madhya Pradesh</option>

                <option value="utp">Uttar Pradesh</option>      

                </select></h3>

            <h3>Select District place : <select name="City">
                        <option>Choose City</option>
                        </select>
            <h3>Select Tehsil place : <select name="Tehsil">
                        <option>Choose City</option>
                        </select>

            </h3><br>

            </center>
        </form><br><br><br>
        </body>
        </html>
```

how to make third level selection ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) *"how to make third level selection ?"* By looking at how the second level is done, and extending that concept to the third. Give it a try, and if you run into a **specific** problem, post your code and a description of the problem you're having with it.

Comment: Side note: `countries` is an array, but it's being used like a non-array object. It should be created via `{}`, not `[]`.

Comment: there is,here on SO, so many similar questions and answers, but people rather just jump here and post question, without any effort to try find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made a solution for my question as follow:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var countries = [ ];
            countries["Madhya Pradesh"] = ["Indore","Jabalpur","Bhopal","Raisen","Rajgarh","Sehore","Vidisha","Morena","Sheopur","Bhind","Ashoknagar","Shivpuri","Rewa"];
            countries["Uttar Pradesh"] = ["Allahabad","Moradabad","Ghaziabad","Azamgarh", "Lucknow","Kanpur Nagar","Jaunpur","Sitapur","Bareilly","Gorakhpur","Agra"];

            var Tehsil = [ ];
            Tehsil["Rewa"] = ["Huzur","Hanumana","Teonthar","Mangawan","Jawa","Sirmour", "Mauganj","Naigarhi","Semaria","Gurh","Raipur - Karchuliyan"];

            function switchCountry(selCountry)
            {
                var citySel = selCountry.form.City;
                for ( var s = citySel.options.length-1; s > 0; --s )  
                {
                    citySel.options[s] = null;
                }

                var chosen = selCountry.options[selCountry.selectedIndex].text;
                var cList = countries[chosen];
                if ( cList != null )
                {
                    for ( var i = 0; i < cList.length; ++i )   
                    {
                        citySel.options[i+1] = new Option(cList[i],cList[i]);
                    }
                }
            }

            function switchCountry1(selCountry)
            {
                var citySel = selCountry.form.Tehsil;
                for ( var s = citySel.options.length-1; s > 0; --s )  
                {
                    citySel.options[s] = null;
                }

                var chosen = selCountry.options[selCountry.selectedIndex].text;
                var cList = Tehsil[chosen];
                if ( cList != null )
                {
                    for ( var i = 0; i < cList.length; ++i )   
                    {
                        citySel.options[i+1] = new Option(cList[i],cList[i]);
                    }
                }
            }


        </script>

        </head>
        <body>  
        <br>
        <form>
            <center>    

                <h3>Select State of shop : <select name="Country" onchange="switchCountry(this);">
                <option value = "">Choose state</option>


                <option value="mdp">Madhya Pradesh</option>

                <option value="utp">Uttar Pradesh</option>      

                </select></h3>

            <h3>Select District place : <select name="City" onchange="switchCountry1(this);">
                        <option>Choose City</option>
                        </select>
            <h3>Select Tehsil place : <select name="Tehsil">
                        <option>Choose Tehsil</option>
                        </select>

            </h3><br>

            </center>
        </form><br><br><br>
        </body>
        </html>
```